Azure DataSync tables not showing up
I'm trying to set up Azure SQL DataSync to go from Azure to a locally hosted SQL DB.
I've set up the hub and member dbs no problem.
When I try to get a list of tables to sync on the hub DB, I get nothing listed, despite the tables having primary keys. If I click the Refresh Schema button, it gets stuck on 'Loading Tables' until I exit the page.

The member DB lists tables fine.
I've noticed that the log has the error 'Failed to connect to server' claiming it failed to login. I can't understand why it would fail to login, the account is my Entra login that is currently a sysadmin (I'm just trying to get it to work before I set it up with dedicated login accounts). Its been used fine in all my other connections to Azure.
Does anyone know what could be causing this (and yes I've checked I've typed the login details correctly many times).


Getting schema information for the database failed with the exception "Failed to connect to server dbservere.database.windows.net.Inner exception: SqlException ID: ef01f3aa-087f-42ff-82fc-b7d9d6c6c11b, Error Code: -2146232060 - SqlError Number:18456, Message: Login failed.  For more information, provide tracing ID ‘c299fe22-89ab-4e6b-94d0-a5545860c438’ to customer support."

The credentials provided may be incorrect while creating Sync Group, that may be the reason to get above error.

the account is my Entra login that is currently a sysadmin

According to the MS document Microsoft Entra (formerly Azure Active Directory) authentication is not currently supported for data sync. That may be the reason to get login failed error. You should use SQL authentication for it. Ensure you have provided correct credentials of your database as shown below:

Then you will be able to load the tables successfully as shown below:


Thanks for that! I wish MS would have put a note on the hub username field saying that...
